# Javascript issue in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel

I'm learning laravel 5 about one month, and now i having a problem with javascript.
I add an form click on blade file to delete the post.
But now i don't want to use form,  i replace that by javascript.
How can i detect when use touch the delete'button.

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section ('head.title')
Blog
@stop

@section ('body.content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            </div>
        </div>

        <form class="form-show">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <h2> {{ $article->title}} </h2>
                    <p>  {{ $article->content}} </p>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <a href=" {{ route('article.edit', $article->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Cập nhật</a>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Xoa</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="jshow.js"></script>
@stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Add id to button so it is easily locatable in Javascript

```
<button id="delete-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Xoa</button>
```

Next add this javascript

```
var deleteButton = document.getElementById("delete-button");
deleteButton.onclick = function() { delete(); return false; }
```

Process the deleting in `delete()` method

Comment: Thanks for help. Let's me try it.

Comment: Terrible sorry, but can you help to answer the new a question.
How can i get ID of the post and delete it on controller through JS.

Comment: Sure, tell me the link of question and accept this answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much.
This is link of new question i had created.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608414/delete-object-on-laravel

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>


 <button onclick="myFun()">Click me</button>

 <p id="demo"></p>

   <script>
 function myFun() {
 console.log('Clicked');
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But it don't work.
In blade file i added
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
            onclick="myfun()">Delete</button>


AND


  <script>
   function myfun()
    {
            console.log('Clicked');
    }
 </script>
But i checked on console and it doesn't log anything.

Comment: I update my solution and it worked for me , try it and tell me what happened

Comment: Thanks for help me. It's worked. I had created new file js and wrote this block source code to js file.

Answer (score 0):

> Since HTML forms can't make `PUT`, `PATCH`, or `DELETE` requests, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to spoof these `HTTP verbs`

Also, don't forget to add `csrf-token` as well which is needed in order to validate a `POST` request.

First add this meta tag inside your `<head>`.

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Then place this code at the top of your JS file.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Now, you can make use of `data-*` attribute to hold the `route` of that article for AJAX.

```
<button data-route="{{ route('article.destroy', $article->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger deleteArticle">Delete</button>
```

In your JS

```
document.querySelector('.deleteArticle').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var route = this.dataset.route;

    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete this article?")) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: route,
            data: {
                "_method": 'DELETE',
            },
            success: function() {
                // handle success here
            },
            error: function() {
                // handle error here
            },
        });
    }
});
```