# Delete object on laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm learning laravel, and now i trying to delete object without form.
i want to use js to detect when user click delete's button and return notify to controller. Then controller with delete object with id has returned from JS file.

This is blade file

```
@extends ('layouts.master')

@section ('head.title')
Blog
@stop

@section ('body.content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            </div>
        </div>

        <form class="form-show">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                    <h2> {{ $article->title}} </h2>
                    <p>  {{ $article->content}} </p>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                        <a href=" {{ route('article.edit', $article->id) }}" class="btn btn-info">Update</a>
                        <button id="delete-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
       <script src="{{ asset('/js/jshow.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

And this is controller file

class ArticlesController extends Controller
    {
        protected $articleModel;

```
    public function __construct(Article $article){
        $this->articleModel = $article;
    }

    public function index(){
        $articles = $this->articleModel->getListArticles();
        // $articles = Article::paginate(10);
        return view('articles.index',compact('articles'));
    }    

    public function show($id){
        // $article = Article::find($id);
        $article = $this->articleModel->getArticleWithID($id);
        return view('articles.show',compact('article'));
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $this->articleModel->deleteArticle($id);
        return redirect()->route('articles.index');
    }
}
```

And here is JS file

```
var deleteButton = document.getElementById("delete-button");
var idPost = document.getElementById("")
deleteButton.onclick = function() { 
    alert('Click to delete');
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You will have to do an ajax request to the server in your event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) from the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) JS library.

Try to understand and to do something, then come back if you any have difficulties.

---

Like [Jerodev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743016/jerodev) said, AJAX calls can be done without jQuery, but I find the jQuery method more understandable. Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) to read more about AJAX using plain JavaScript.

Comment: ajax can be done without jQuery or with other libraries as well.

Comment: Correct, but I find AJAX calls easier with jQuery. But yeah, jQuery is optional.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX Request in Jquery is that for you ...

first learn how AJAX Work to request server .

use jquery to easy that for you .

remake delete function to make it more able with AJAX Request to just delete the object and response data .

```
public function delete(Request $req)
    {
$this->articleModel->deleteArticle($id);
return response()->json(['msg' => 'some Msg help]);
    }
```

make route for this function .

then make the ajax request to get this route and delete the object and return the msg you make .

but you must first Learn AJAX .